# Displaying an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
ArrayList <String> cdcollection = new ArrayList();

private void initButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Collections.addAll(cdcollection, "small", "mayre", "brown", "evner", "rain" );
    initButton.setEnabled(false);

}

private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

          for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++)  {
          mainTextArea.setText(cdcollection.get(i));
    }
}

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    cdcollection.add(cdtitleInput.getText());
}

private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    cdcollection.remove(cdcollection.size()-1);
}
```

When I run this and click the display button only the last cd title (rain) appears... 
How can I get all five cd titles to appear each on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do changes in `displayButtonActionPerformed` method as shown below.

```
private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++)  {
          str = str + cdcollection.get(i);
    }
    mainTextArea.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works better because append affects the add button by adding the whole collection when pressed.

Comment: Simplified for-loop isn't for you?

Answer (score 8):

Use `Append()` instead of `setText()`

Comment: You can do line splits with \n . If you have to, you can also use setText() to clear the box, before using append().

Answer (score 0):

Use the simplified for-loop.

```
private void displayButtonActionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {    
    for (String cd : cdcollection) {
          mainTextArea.append (cd + "\n");
    }
}
```

It will often prevent off-by-one errors, it is often shorter and it is better readable.